# What mean resilient, robust and resistant algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I have problems with certain algorithmic terms.

What is a robust algorithm ?
What is a resistant algorithm ?
What is a resilient algorithms ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These attributes have no exact definition. So it depends on your topic/problem what they mean.

They are all used to describe algorithms that can cope with some kind of errors (e.g. outlier or noise) in the input-data and still deliver a useful / the expected result.

So in general you define the kind of errors the algorithm is expected to handle in a defined way.

E.g *'This algorithm returns for an input with less than 5% outlier a result with an accuracy of 99%.'*